# Need help finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lfloor \pi\cdot10^n\rfloor \bmod 10$

Tags: limits, pi

I want to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lfloor \pi\cdot10^n\rfloor \bmod 10$$

I think the answer could be something in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You are asking for the limiting value of the digits in $\pi$?

Comment: This question basically seems to amount to asking "what is the last digit of $\pi$?" The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I could try a numerical approximation.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lfloor \theta\cdot10^n\rfloor \bmod 10$ exists iff $\theta=\frac{m}{9\cdot 10^r}$

Comment: There is no numerical approximation involved.  that expression reaches a limit, for $\alpha$ in place of $\pi$ iff $\alpha$ is rational with a period of $1$.  So, for $\alpha =\frac 13$ the limit is $3$.  For $\alpha = \frac 14$ it is $0$.  But for everything else, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Ihf I think you are missing the numbers with finitely many nonzero digits :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, you can take $m$ to be a multiple of $9$.

Comment: @Ihf Indeed, I completely missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist.

- The sequence $a_n = \lfloor \pi \cdot 10^n \rfloor \mod 10$ is a sequence of integers.
- A sequence of integers converges if and only if it is eventually constant.
- A number with an eventually constant sequence of digits is rational.
- $\pi$ isn't rational.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\pi & = 3\,.\,1415926535\ldots \\
& \qquad \searrow \\[8pt]
10^5\pi & = 314159\,.\,26535\ldots \\
& ( \text{multiplying by $10^5$ just moves the} \\
& \phantom{(} \text{ decimal point 5 places leftward.)} \\[8pt]
\lfloor10^5\pi\rfloor & = 314159 \\[8pt]
\lfloor10^5\pi\rfloor & \bmod 10 = 9 \\
& (x\bmod10= \text{the last digit of the positive integer }x.) \\[18pt]
\text{So } & \lfloor 10^n\pi\rfloor = \text{the $n$th digit after the decimal point in } \pi.
\end{align}